# Asp.net mvc, modifying SelectList

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to write simple extension method for SelectList. API confuses me.

```
public static SelectList Without(this SelectList selectList,int val){
  //return new SelectList(selectList.Items.Where(x=>x.Value!=val)); <-----???
}
```

It should return new select list with same items w/o one which value matches argument `val`.

Comment: Could you expand on which bit of your method is not working?

Comment: @Mark `selectList.Items.Where(x=>x.Value!=val)` because `Items.GetType==typeof(IEnumerable)`

Answer (score 1):

This works. Likely is a bit slow, but I don't care:

```
public static class SelectListExtensions{
  public static SelectList Without
   (this SelectList selectList, params int[] what){
    var items=selectList.Items.Cast<dynamic>()
      .Where(x=>!what.Any(z=>x.Value==z));
    return new SelectList(items);
  }
  public static SelectList Without<T>
   (this SelectList selectList,params T[] what) where T:Enumeration{
    var items=selectList.Items.Cast<dynamic>()
      .Where(x=>!what.Any(z=>x.Value==z.Value));
    return new SelectList(items);
  }
}
```

Better approaches are welcome.

---

Nope. That does not work. Rendered Html:

```
<select data-val="true" data-val-required="The JMC decision field is required." 
 id="JMCDecisionStatus" name="JMCDecisionStatus">
 <option>{ Name = Successful, Value = 2 }</option>
 <option>{ Name = Reserved, Value = 3 }</option>
 <option>{ Name = Rejected, Value = 4 }</option>
</select>
```

Not exactly what I was looking for. :D

Answer (score 0):

Do you just need to apply a ToArray() to your IEnumerable collection??

```
return new SelectList(selectList.Items.Where(x=>x.Value!=val).ToArray());
```

Comment: Nope. Commented below my question. Problem is that Items is collection from objects. `x` does not have `Value`.

Comment: @Arnis. Ah, okay. Disregard my answer then. I have voted up your answer instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
return new SelectList(selectList.Items.Cast<T>().Except(what));
```